# Countdown starts without a click event

Tags: javascript

Question from a JS learner.

I'm making a countdown from 10 to 0 for this game like project. However, the countdown starts without a click event. I want it to start as an event listener but I don't know how to stop this function from running.

```
   <div class="display-buttons-container">
     <div class="display">10</div>
     <button id="arm">Arm</button>
     <button id="disarm">Disarm</button>
   </div>
```

```
  const btnArm = document.querySelector("#arm");
  const btnDisarm = document.querySelector("#disarm");
  const countdown = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
  const countdownDisplay =   document.querySelector(".display");
  let i = 0;

  btnArm.addEventListener("click", countdownFunction());

  function countdownFunction() {
  countdownDisplay.innerHTML = countdown[i];
  ++i;

  if (i > 10) countdownDisplay.innerHTML = 0;
  }

  setInterval(countdownFunction, 1000);
```

Comment: `btnArm.addEventListener("click", startTimer());` - `function startTimer() { setInterval(countdownFunction, 1000); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `setInterval` is not inside the `countdownFunction` function thats the reason it running without any click event.

and to stop the timer you can use `clearInterval(intervalID)` which is used to clear a timer that is set with the `setInterval()` method.

```js
const btnArm = document.querySelector("#arm");
const btnDisarm = document.querySelector("#disarm");
// no need of this array you can use a single variable instead
// const countdown = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
let count = 10;
let intervalID;
const countdownDisplay =   document.querySelector(".display");

function startTimer() {
  count = 10;
  // clearing timer in case user wants to restart the timer
  if (intervalID) {
      clearInterval(intervalID); // clearing timer
      intervalID = undefined; // resetting intervalID
  }

  // intervalID will be used to clear the timer
  intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    if (count === 0 && intervalID) {
      clearInterval(intervalID); // clearing timer
      intervalID = undefined; // resetting intervalID
    }
     countdownDisplay.innerHTML = count;
     --count;
  }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
  // clearing timer if intervalID is defined i.e. if any timer is in running state.
  if (intervalID) {
      clearInterval(intervalID); // clearing timer
      intervalID = undefined; // resetting intervalID
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="display-buttons-container">
     <div class="display">10</div>
     <button id="arm" onclick="startTimer()">Arm</button>
     <button id="disarm" onclick="stopTimer()">Disarm</button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the parentheses after `countdownFunction` to stop it from running the function immediately

You need to save the interval id returned from [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

you can call [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) and pass the interval id as the parameter and it will stop the interval

```js
const btnArm = document.querySelector("#arm");
const btnDisarm = document.querySelector("#disarm");
const countdown = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
const countdownDisplay = document.querySelector(".display");
let i = 0;

let intervalId

function countdownFunction() {
  countdownDisplay.innerHTML = countdown[i];

  ++i;

  if (i > 10) countdownDisplay.innerHTML = 0;
}

btnArm.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (intervalId) return

  intervalId = setInterval(countdownFunction, 1000)
});

btnDisarm.addEventListener("click", () => clearInterval(intervalId))
```

```html
<div class="display-buttons-container">
  <div class="display">10</div>
  <button id="arm">Arm</button>
  <button id="disarm">Disarm</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally prefer `setTimeout` for this kind of operation. That said the key to this is to declare a variable that can hold the timer that both the arm/disarm functions can use to either set the timer or clear the timer respectively.

1. `btnArm.addEventListener("click", countdownFunction());` assigns the returned value of *calling* the function to the listener. Unless you're returning a function you don't want to do this.   `btnArm.addEventListener("click", countdownFunction);` assigns a reference to the function instead.
2. I've made all the elements identifiable by class for consistency.
3. Added new function that clears the timer.
4. Removed the requirement for an array - you can just set a default for the current count.
5. Used `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`.

```js
// Cache the elements
const arm = document.querySelector('.arm');
const disarm = document.querySelector('.disarm');
const display = document.querySelector('.display');

// Set up the listeners
arm.addEventListener('click', start);
disarm.addEventListener('click', stop);

// Declare the timer variable
let timer;

function start() {

  // When `start` is called it immediately calls
  // `loop` with default count of 10
  function loop(count = 10) {

    // If count > 0 display the count, and call loop
    // again with a reduced count
    if (count > 0) {
      display.textContent = count;
      timer = setTimeout(loop, 1000, --count);

    // Otherwise "Boom!"
    } else {
      display.textContent = ' Boom! ';
    }
  }

  // Call the loop for the first time
  loop();

}

// If "disarm" is called clear the timer
function stop() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  display.textContent = 'Disarmed';
}
```

```css
button { font-size: 1.2rem; padding: 0.4em 0.8em; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; border-radius: 5px; margin: 0.5em 0.25em; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid #454545; }
.arm { background-color: salmon; }
.disarm { background-color: lightgreen; }
.display { margin: 1em 0.25em; font-size: 1.6rem; }
```

```html
<button class="arm">Arm</button>
<button class="disarm">Disarm</button>
<div class="display"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you Andy for such a detailed explanation. Your solutions also works.